# CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement.?

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have the following update code in my controller.
The sql query is executing correctly and I can see the updated result in backend.
But while executing its showing error, 'CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement'.
Is there any other way to write this statement. Contoller codes are as follow.

```
public function actionactiveuser()
 {          

 $user_id=$_GET['id'];
 $query = "UPDATE user SET status = '1' WHERE id = '$user_id'";
 Yii::app()->db->createCommand($query)->queryAll();
 $this->render('login');    
 }
```

It is showing error:

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error. The SQL statement executed was: UPDATE user SET status = '1' WHERE id = '80'
```

Comment: Thats tricky. Is your MySql setup correctly in your php.ini? For Yii you need pdo. Best to run the Yii requirements check and see if there is any error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change this

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand($query)->queryAll();
```

to

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand($query)->execute();
```

**queryAll()** is used for select queries. **execute()** is for Update and Insert queries

**BTW** For the safety you should do something like this

```
$query = "UPDATE user SET status = :status' WHERE id = :id";
 Yii::app()->db->createCommand($query)->execute(array(':status' => '1',':id'=>$user_id ));
```